# Sync SQL Server to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have old apps which using VB6 and SQL Server 2000. This apps is build for offline purpose. Now, we want to get daily report via Online through website.

```
[local]
VB6
SQL Server 2000

[VPS]
PHP7
Mysql
```

What i done is, create install XAMPP in local server then use cronjob every 10min to execute sync.php which will syncronize db from SQL Server to Mysql.

My script flow:

```
foreach (SQL_SERVER_RESULT)
{
if(!checkExistOrNotInMysql()) insertDataToMysql()
}
```

I just check if data is already stored in VPS or not. If not, data will be inserted.

**The Problem is** : i cant check if data in SQL server is **UPDATED**. If i check updated data, it will force me to check **WHOLE** data in Mysql in every Cronjob (bad thing).

So, my question is, what is the best way to do this?

thanks for advance.

Comment: How many tables are there? You could add a `AFTER UPDATE` trigger to capture updates and alter your query to grab these values as well.

Comment: If it were me, I would, on SQL Server, set up a linked server to MySQL.  Then I would write stored procedures that get me what I want from each database.

Comment: sorry for late reply, i just wake up today @EvaldasBuinauskas i want sync 10 of 20 tables. (But maybe all of them if possible). The existing data is 1000 in each table. I can build trigger `AFTER UPDATE` but i cant do it cross server (server to another server). And if this can happen, i still dont know if this will work with Mysql as second db. Can you give me a link or try to answer please.

Comment: @DanBracuk your answer sounds interesting. but i just dont know how to do that. I never call trigger to run SQL query from SQL Server to Mysql. Can you give me example or just link. i will appreciate that.

Comment: omg. i found this http://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/07/22/link-mysql-to-ms-sql-server2008/ .i will try it now